# Obtain the swagger document for a REST service

Tags: rest, web-services, swagger

The standard way to obtain a WSDL for a SOAP service is `http://server/xxx?wsdl` (`?wsdl` appended to the service uri).

Is there a similar standardised mechanism for making available the swagger specification of a REST service? Or do I have to use an API management service? Using `?swagger` doesn't make sense to me...